# How to do fade-in sound in Python??

Tags: python

def fade_in (snd, fade_length):
'''doing a sound fade-in for that wave file'''
    new_snd = sound.copy(snd)

```
for sample in new_snd:
    snd_index = sound.get_index(sample)
    factor = 0
    snd_samp = sound.get_sample(snd, snd_index)
    if snd_index <= fade_length:
        left = (sound.get_left(snd_samp) * factor)
        right = (sound.get_right(snd_samp) * factor)
        factor += 0.25
        sound.set_values(sample,int(left),int(right))
    else:
        left = sound.get_left(sample)
        right = sound.get_right(sample)
        sound.set_values(sample, int(left), int(right))

return new_snd
```

Comment: That's just a block of code. You have to ask a question.

Comment: i tried to write a code to do fade in sound in python but then this code is not working. in the part  if snd_index <= fade_length:
        left = (sound.get_left(snd_samp) * factor)
        right = (sound.get_right(snd_samp) * factor) 
        factor += 0.25
        sound.set_values(sample,int(left),int(right))in this part i printed the value of left and right but they are all 0 i don't understand why

Comment: oh actually i figure it out but now i have a new problem when the snd_index <= fade_length part. when it is running that part it get some weird sound nothing like the oringinal but went it done this part it back to normal

Answer (score 0):

`left` and `right` will always be zero, as you set `factor` to zero every run in the for-loop. You have to declare `factor` outside of the for-loop:

```
def fade_in (snd, fade_length):
    new_snd = sound.copy(snd)
    factor = 0

    for sample in new_snd:
        snd_index = sound.get_index(sample)
        snd_samp = sound.get_sample(snd, snd_index)
        if snd_index <= fade_length:
            left = (sound.get_left(snd_samp) * factor)
            right = (sound.get_right(snd_samp) * factor)
            factor += 0.25
            sound.set_values(sample,int(left),int(right))
        else:
            left = sound.get_left(sample)
            right = sound.get_right(sample)
            sound.set_values(sample, int(left), int(right))

    return new_snd
```